# How do I add two python dictionaries such that the not equal thinks become zero?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a little bit of help here. I am a new python coder. I need a lot of help. So, I want to add the different variables in two dictionaries. An example is:

```
x = {'a':1, 'b':2}

y = {'b':1, 'c':2}
```

I want to replace these values such that it looks like:

```
x = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':0}

y = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2}
```

Comment: which python version are you actually using, you've tagged both 2.7 and 3.x. That makes it confusing when using methods such as `.viewkeys()` because on Py 3 it's changed to `.keys()`

Comment: I am using python 3. Sorry for the confusion. Did not expect so many replies in 4 minutes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> x = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> y = {'b':1, 'c':2}
>>> for k in y:
...  x.setdefault(k, 0)
... 
0
2
>>> for k in x:
...  y.setdefault(k, 0)
... 
0
2
1
>>> x
{'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 2}
>>> y
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: Good Modesty Ashwini! Keep it up! And, great answer gnibbler! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> x = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> y = {'b':1, 'c':2}
>>> keys = x.viewkeys() | y.viewkeys()  #returns union of keys in x and y
>>> x = {k : x.get(k,0) for k in keys}
>>> y = {k : y.get(k,0) for k in keys}
>>> x
{'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 2}
>>> y
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```

change the dict in-place:

```
>>> x = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> y = {'b':1, 'c':2}
>>> diff_x = y.viewkeys() - x.viewkeys()
>>> diff_y = x.viewkeys() - y.viewkeys()
#if you're using a mutable object as value instead of 0,
#then you've to use a dict comprehension instead of dict.fromkeys.
>>> x.update(dict.fromkeys(diff_x,0))
>>> y.update(dict.fromkeys(diff_y,0))
>>> x
{'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 2}
>>> y
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```

Comment: It would be better to use a generator expression instead of a `dict` comprehension or `dict.fromkeys` to pass to `dict.update` since it evaluates lazily.

Answer (score 1):

This solution would be good if you need a new dictionary as a result:

```
>>> x = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> y = {'b':1, 'c':2}
>>> dict(dict.fromkeys(y, 0), **x)
{'a': 1, 'c': 0, 'b': 2}
>>> dict(dict.fromkeys(x, 0), **y)
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```